# How to allow filtering Films in my app intuitively? (GUI design)

Tags: filter

I am not sure if this is the right place to ask this but I wrote an app that shows all the movies in one's computer with the appropriate info such as genre, director, rating, etc.

I am wondering how can I make it so that the user can filter them based on criteria such as genre, rating, etc?

Most of them are enums, and I was thinking of using a `ComboBox` for these but they should be able to specify more than 1 genre. So should I use `ListBox` controls for these? Then it will be harder to present all these options in listboxes.

I haven't seen any examples of apps doing similar things, that's why I am not sure.

Any ideas?

[image]

Btw I don't have any competitor apps per se because I am making this sort of a small size app where I want to show these filtering in a very easily presentable way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could make it an Autocomplete Input box similar to Tumblr's tags mechanism. Logically if it is their computer, they should have a good idea of what genres to type in, and the autocomplete will help them.

Here is a screenshot of Tumblr's tags mechanism.
[image: tags]

In the mechanism, the user types a list of words and when the user hits ',' the word displays as a green box, showing that the word has been added.